# Определить текущую раскладку BASH

Tags: ubuntu, bash, клавиатура

Как определить текушую раскладку клавиатуры с помощью bash?

Пробовал так:

```
xset -q | awk 'BEGIN { a[1]="ru"; a[0]="en" } /LED/ { print a[substr($10,5,1)]; }'
```

Но этот код всегда выдает "en", независимо от раскладки.

ОС Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Вы не могли бы уточнить какая у вас Система? 

Comment: ой извините, у меня ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

За управление раскладкой в консоли отвечает команда `setxkbmap`, а при запуске с параметром `-print` она показывает текущее положение дел.

```
$ setxkbmap -print

xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete+ledscroll(group_lock)"    };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+ru+us:2+inet(evdev)+compose(caps)"  };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

Если немного поиграться, можно достать вот эти вот **`ru`**:

```
$ setxkbmap -print | sed -n 's#xkb_symbols[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*$#\1#p' | awk -F+ '{print $2}'
ru
```

При переключении раскладки сменится на **`us`**.

Comment: *При переключении раскладки смениться на* — увы, не сменится.

Comment: В Ubuntu 14.04 — меняется вроде. У вас какая ОС?

Comment: *У вас какая ОС?* — понятно, что *gnu/linux*. // без перезагрузки новой конфигурации xkb в выводе setxkbmap или чего-либо иного, способного запросить у xkb текущую конфигурацию, например, того же xkbcomp, ничего не поменяется. // текущий layout — это **состояние** (state), а не конфигурация.

Comment: Простите, какой у вас дистрибутив? При смене раскладки вывод `$ setxkbmap -print | grep xkb_symbols` меняется с `xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+inet(evdev)+compose(caps)" };` на `xkb_symbols   { include "pc+ru+us:2+inet(evdev)+compose(caps)" };` в Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: дистрибутив debian. интересный у вас установлен «переключатель раскладки». неужели он для **каждого** переключения производит перезагрузку конфигурации? может быть, вы используете больше четырёх раскладок — тогда, действительно, без перезагрузки конфигурации не обойтись — в x-протоколе «зашито» жёсткое ограничение на количество group — под них отводится всего два бита информации.

Comment: а вы чем-нибудь тип xneur или подобного не пользуетесь, случайно?

Comment: Нет, не пользуюсь

Comment: разобрался. это «гениальные» писатели desktop-environment-ов так чудят. я собрал воедино информацию в [соседнем ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/442182/178576).

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04, пользуюсь `$ setxkbmap -print...`, а вот `$ xset -q | sed...` всегда выдаёт `0`. Хоткеи на переключение раскладки не менял, языки En/Ru.

Answer (score 3):

компиляция из ответов (и добавка от меня) к [этому](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12072/110559) вопросу:

---

штатного «из-коробочного» средства определить выбранную сейчас раскладку (группу — *group* — в терминологии *xkb*) — нет.

1. довольно близка к решению программа `xset`, запущенная с опцией `-q`. можно отличтить первую раскладку от всех остальных:

   ```
   $ xset -q | sed -rn 's/.*LED mask.*(.)[[:xdigit:]]{3}$/\1/p'
   ```

   для первой раскладки эта команда вернёт `0`, для всех остальных — `1`.

   если вы используете всего две раскладки, то это подходящее решение.
2. некоторые криво спроектированные (моё оценочное суждение) «переключатели раскладок» (например, встроенный в современные версии *gnome* апплет) вместо изменения раскладки полностью перезагружают всю конфигурацию *xkb*, в чём несложно убедиться, сравнив выводы команды `xkbcomp $DISPLAY -` при выборе разных языков через такой апплет (или клавиатурным сокращением, вызывающим тот же код).

   если вы — «счастливый» обладатель такого «переключателя», то вот такая команда выдаст наименование **переконфигурированной** в данный момент раскладки:

   ```
   $ xkbcomp $DISPLAY - | sed -nr 's/.*name\[group1\]="([^"]+)".*/\1/p'
   ```

   примеры её вывода: `English (US)`, `Russian` и т.п.
3. для не столь «счастливых» людей выходом остаётся, пожалуй, только сборка какой-нибудь вспомогательной программы типа:

   - https://github.com/ierton/xkb-switch
   - https://github.com/nonpop/xkblayout-state

   или чего-то подобного.

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой любительский, но рабочий вариант без sed, awk, perl и т.д. Старался решить это силами bash, чтоб работал быстрее и экономичнее.

```
xset -q | while read -r line ; do [[ $line = *Group* ]] && line=${line//13*} && ([[ $line = *off* ]] && echo 'EN ' || echo 'RU ') && exit ; done
```

Вылавливаем значения "Group 2:     on/off" из этой строки:

```
12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
```

Comment: у меня всегда off

Answer (score 0):

```
xset -q|grep Group\ 2|awk {'print $4'}|sed 's/on/ru/g;s/off/en/g'
```

Answer (score -2):

```
xset -q|grep Group\ 2|awk {'print $4'}|sed 's/on/en/g;s/off/ru/g'
```