# Не работают хоткеи в Fedora 21 (KDE)

Tags: linux, hotkeys, fedora, kde

В свежеустановленной Fedora 21 (KDE 4.14.6) не работают хоткеи. В основном проблема проявляется с комбинациями, в которых больше двух клавиш (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>, etc), но также не вызывается по <kbd>F12</kbd> свежеустановленный `yakuake`.

Как это можно исправить? Или более общий вопрос - как и где вообще в Федоре настраиваются хоткеи?

Comment: переключалка языков - ctrl+shift ?

Comment: @KoVadim да, именно

Comment: известная бага, которую не фиксят, так как англоязычным переключение не нужно, а все остальные перешли на CapsLock. Я сам лично использую CapsLock и очень доволен.

Comment: Да, переход на CapsLock помогает. А что делать, если я привык использовать эту клавишу по прямому назначению, а раскладку переключать через ctrl+shift?

Comment: - перейти на винду
- не использовать CapsLock - нет ни одной причины (разве что только что бы покричать)
- запились фикс в Xorg самостоятельно

Comment: Спасибо, ваш совет очень мне помог. *sarcasm*

Comment: @KoVadim Алсо, у коллеги на Ubuntu+KDE прекрасно работает ctrl+shift, причём тут вообще переход на винду?

Comment: Возможно у него переключалка стоит на другой комбинации (Alt-Shift).

Comment: Нет, именно ctrl-shift, иначе бы не упоминал его.

И это ведь не должно всё затрагивать F12, кстати?

Comment: я KDE не пользовался уже очень много лет, но, к примеру, в XFCE есть глобальные shortcut, и если туда добавить F12, то другие программы не смогут его использовать. Смотртие в "System Settings > Input Actions".

Кстати, вполне возможно, что на нужные комбинации у Вас забиндено что то в виде "развернуть окно в пол экрана" и тому подобное.

Comment: *у коллеги на Ubuntu+KDE прекрасно работает ctrl+shift* — это не «прекрасное» решение, а чудовищного вида «костыль». см. второй пункт в [этом](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/442182/178576) ответе.

Comment: @alexander-barakin да ладно, если в Ubuntu *из коробки* работает привычное домашним пользователям (особенно мигрировавшим с Windows) "стандартное" сочетание ctrl+shift - это костыль? ни автору вопроса, ни сферическому в вакууме юзеру не интересны причины - интересно "сделать, шоб работало"

Comment: @AntonioK, может быть, на таких пользователей подействует аргумент вида «когда ты переключаешь раскладку в последних версиях *gnome*, умирает котёнок»?

Comment: @alexander-barakin то есть, я правильно понимаю, Вы предлагаете юзерам переучиваться на переключение языков Caps Lock'ом только потому, что реализация переключения привычными им шорткатами крива изнутри? у ТС, кстати, не Gnome, а KDE.

Comment: @AntonioK, 1. нет, я не предлагаю «переучиваться на переключение языков capslock-ом». если уж я что-то и предлагаю из «этой оперы», то переучиться на **в**ключение (а не **пере**ключение) раскладок какими-нибудь клавишами (или их сочетаниями). подробнее можно прочитать в одной из моих «[заметок на „полях“ клавиатуры](http://unixforum.org/index.php?showtopic=49203)». 2. *у ТС, кстати, не Gnome, а KDE* — совершенно верно. иначе он не озадачивался бы вопросом *сделтать, шоб работало*,

Comment: Тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой в Fedora (KDE). Перешел на shift+CapsLock - почти как привычный мне ctrl+shift, а CapsLock тоже не хотелось занимать под переключение - иногда использую по прямому назначению.

Answer (score 1):

В KDE, если открыть главное меню (по типу как нажать кнопку "Пуск" в Windows) есть пункт в какой-то из вкладок, называется **"System setings"** (в локализоаванной KDE **"Параметры системы"**).

Так должен быть такой пункт, как **"Shortcuts and Gestures"** (**"Комбинации клавиш и росчерки"**). Зайдя в него, слева в панели есть три различных меню.
Тебе нужно выбрать **"Custom Shortcut"**.

В меню правее видишь различные папки (колонка с именем "Name") - выбираешь "Examples". Далее - либо ПКМ либо ниже есть пункт "edit", выбираешь:
`"new" -> "global shortcut" -> "Command\URL"` -- повесить на кастомный хоткей какую-то команду, по типу dolphin\chrome\etc...

Так же можно поиграться с остальнымы пунктами в подпункте **"global shortcut"**.

p.s. сам юзаю Debian 8.2, но стоит KDE 4. Так что, надеюсь, что помог.