# Постоянно сбиваются настройки xkb

Tags: ubuntu, клавиатура

Ноутбук - asus x541s. Ось - ubuntu server 16.10. Оконный менеджер (менеджер окон, если так корректней) - i3wm. Клавиатура vinga подсоединенная к ноуту через хаб. Настроил xkb следующим образом - создал файлик `~/.config/xkbconf` со следующим конфигом:

```
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  {
              # меняем кнопки местами
              include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)"
                  #<LCTL> = 37;
              #<CAPS> = 66;
                  #<LWIN> = 133;
              <LCTL> = 66;
              <CAPS> = 133;
              <LWIN> = 37;
    };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    {
              # зажигаем scroll lock при русской раскладке 
              include "complete"
              include "ledscroll(group_lock)"
              };
    xkb_symbols   {
              include "pc+us+ru(ruu):2+inet(evdev)+capslock(grouplock)"
    };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

и при загрузки x-ов выполняю команду `xkbcomp .config/xkbconf $DISPLAY`. Все работает. Но периодически настройки слетает к "дефолтным" (капс снова становится капсом, контрол контролом и т.д.). Закономерность сбоя уследить не удается никоим образом. Повесил команду `xkbcomp .config/xkbconf $DISPLAY` на комбинацию клавиш win-f1. Нажатие комбинации сразу исправляет ситуацию, но сбой порой происходит в момент набора текста, что дико доставляет. Есть идеи в чем проблема и как ее можно решить?

Comment: зачем на server X-ы? а настройки могут слететь, если произошел какой-то сбой(исключение). Пробовал драйвер клавы обновить?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, это домашний ноут. Ubuntu Server поставил потому что в качестве менеджера окон интересует именно i3wm. Драйверов к клаве никаких не было. Google за дрова тоже молчит

Comment: без дров твоя клава не работала бы. поищи последние драйвера именно для твоей клавы в Инете, обнови и посмотри. но проверь. что версия новая. У тебя драйвер "по умолчанию" стоит в системе

Comment: [Вот все](https://www.google.com.ua/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=vinga+kb600bk+ubuntu&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=k-CJWL7QFOiDuAH05au4AQ) что гугл может найти по моей клаве)) Драйверов и близко нет

Comment: см. пункт 2 из [этого ответа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/442182/178576).

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, *Пробовал драйвер клавы обновить?* — это такой тончайший троллинг? боюсь, что далеко не все посетители ru.so смогут его оценить.