# Нециклическое переключение раскладки клавиатуры не работает с некоторыми программами

Tags: linux, gnome

Возникла необходимость использовать Gnome3. Нашёл привычные (почти) настройки переключения раскладки: <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> - английский, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> - русский, а так же <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> (пока нажат) - "на другую". Делается это через Tweak Tool → Typing → Switch to another layout.

Проблема в <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>: при использовании приложений Gnome (консоль, Nautilus, и тд) всё работает как должно, а вот **в chrome, telegram, vscode** переключение по <kbd>Alt</kbd> работает только с русского на английский, но не наоборот.

Как обойти эту ошибку в указанных программах?

Comment: вопрос про индикатор явно не имеет отношения к описанной неработоспособности. здесь несвязанные вопросы принято задавать по отдельности.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin насчёт несвязанных вопросов понял, согласен. А вот насчёт правки про "указанные программы" не согласен, это не полный список программ, где не работает, а локальные хаки отдельных программ не будут являться решением.

Comment: попробуйте выяснить объединяющий признак. судя по приведённому списку, это какие-то «левые» (т.е., установленные не из репозитория дистрибутива) программы.

Comment: Из дистрибутивных программ не работают gimp (inkscape работает), blender, firefox, wine (что попробовал под ним).
Сначала думал, что это qt (telegram точно на qt, chrome вроде использует), но gimp и firefox разубедили. Пока только одна догадка: может быть те программы, что не работают перехватывают Alt для хоткеев каким-то более низкоуровневым образом, что gnome не может на него отреагировать. Но если это так, то тут просто поправить конфиг не поможет. До последнего надеюсь на местных знатоков.

Comment: *До последнего надеюсь на местных знатоков* — те космических масштабов костыли, которые гномовцы (или убунтовцы или фиг его знает кто) вкорячили вместо стандартного иксового механизма переключения раскладок (см. пункт 2 в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/442182/178576)), увы, отбивают всякую охоту в этой зелёной субстанции ковыряться.

Comment: gnome != ubuntu, данная проблема в fedora