# Переключение языка на отжатие в Ubuntu/Debian (KDE,Gnome)

Tags: ubuntu, debian, gnome, kde

После апгрейда Ubuntu KDE plasma с 16.04 до 17.04 заметил странную вещь (да и в последних релизах 18.04). Переключение языков срабатывает на **нажатия** клавиш, а не **отжатие** как было раньше.

Это было замечено также и на Debian 9 с Gnome 3.

Это проблема, так как, например, если нужно с браузере отменить закрытую вкладку `Ctrl+Shift+T`,  действие не срабатывает, так как после сочетания `Ctrl+Shift` переключается язык.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой и как её фиксить?

**PS**: Ответы по типу "измени на `alt+shift`" предлагать не нужно.

Comment: [Была такая проблема раньше](https://habr.com/post/87408/) , для современных версий убунты с гномом не проверял.

Comment: Читал этот хабр, но там пачт под 10.04, на 17-18.04/Debian 9 не подойдет, а понять идею патча и переписать его под мои требование не смогу, не силен.

Comment: вы для начала определитесь, [действительно ли у вас происходит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/442182/178576) **переключение раскладок**, а не криворукая перезагрузка всей конфигурации xkb.

Comment: переключение проходит и это не криворукая перезагрузка всей конфигурации xkb. После чистой установки Debian 9 уже существует эта проблема.

Comment: @VitaliyKalyuzhnyak  [Нашел такой способ](https://askubuntu.com/a/967493) , можно переопределить уровень нажатия клавиш.

Comment: Черным по белому написано: Ответы по типу "измени на alt+shift" предлагать не нужно.
В твоем случае "переопределить" именно это и подразумевает.

Comment: @VitaliyKalyuzhnyak  По приведенной ссылке в разделе `Switching to another layout` нужно поставить галку напротив `Ctrl+Shift` , что  "пробросит" (переопределит на другой уровень, цепочка проверки сочетания будет другая). Про `alt+shift` и не подразумевал.

Comment: Но ведь это обычное переназначение клавиш. Это не решит проблему, о которой я писал.