# Ускорить переключение раскладки клавиатуры Elementary OS

Tags: linux, клавиатура, elementary-os

У меня небольшая проблема. Слишком долго переключается раскладка клавиатуры, где-то 1-2 сек. Использую Linux дистрибутив Elementary OS 5 Juno (Основанный на Ubuntu). Переключение у меня стоит на <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>.
Кто в теме, помогите. При работе в IDE слишком усложняет работу. Буду очень признателен.

Comment: самый радикальный метод — настроить именно самое обычно нормальное переключение раскладки (встроенными средствами xkb), а не как наверняка у вас сейчас сделано (см. пункт 2 в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/442182/178576)) — методом перегрузки **всей конфигурации xkb**, да ещё и из внешней программы. (т.е., видимо, начинать надо с «выбрасывания» чего-то под названием «апплет для переключения раскладок»)

Comment: Извините, но я не профи-линуксоид. Можно как нибудь по доступней пожалуйста? В интернете я ничего не нашел по этой проблеме, а менять дистрибутив, да еще и такой красивый (дизайн у него действительно супер) лишь потому, что долго переключается клавиатура как-то глупо.

Comment: менять надо не дистрибутив операционной системы, а «то», где реализован этот идиотизм (моё оценочное суждение). т.е., *de* (*desktop environment*). это если не хотите тратить время на следование первому совету. менять дистрибутив не имеет смысла и по иной причине — в большинстве популярных дистрибутивов используется тот же самый *de* с тем же самым идиотизмом на борту. // впрочем, есть некоторая вероятность, что ваша конкретная проблема в большей степени диктуется какими-нибудь иными причинами, а упомянутый идиотизм лишь добавляет некоторую долю задержки.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin на самом деле смена дистрибутива - вариант (крайний конечно). другие дистрибутивы не используют тот же de, что и elementary. он у них свой, уникальный. такой же бедой страдает другой похожий дистрибутив - deepin. в gnome, xfce и kde переключение мгновенное.

Answer (score 1):

Мне помогло это.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Но перед этим ещё установил:

```
python3 -m pip install --user pynput==1.4
```

Но болше ни чего не делал! скрипт switch-layout.py не кидал в домашнию директорию и не настраивал и не запуска!
 С ангилийского на русский переключается все равно с очень маленкой задержкой, наооборот - моментально!

Answer (score 0):

[В elementary os раскладка переключается с задержкой](https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/desktop/14619361)

ответ meliafaro

P.S. На всякий случай привожу описание с гитхаба ("как есть"):

> switch-layout
>   What is this?

This is a workaround for keyboard layout switching bug, which occurs, as far as I know, on some Gnome 3 based DEs running on X server, including Pantheon (elementary OS DE). According to some of the reports I've read, it affects mostly users of Russian keyboard layout.

The bug is this: there is an annoying delay between the moment you try to switch layout (either with a shortcut or with the GUI) and the moment the layout is switched. In my case, it's around 1 second when switching from RU to EN. Sometimes the layout doesn't switch at all! This bug makes it impossible to type text both in Russian and English quickly.

This workaround made things easier for me. It's not ideal, but it reduces the delay far enough to make it barely noticable.

Related reports on Launchpad:

```
Delay before you can type after switching input source
Gnome on Xorg freezes for short time on every keyboard layout switch
layout switch is delayed
```

How does it work

I've found that I can switch my layout using gsettings command without any delay:

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current X

Where X is the index of a layout: 0 for the first one, 1 for the second, etc.

This script listens to the switch shortcut and runs the command itself.
How to install it

```
Make sure you have pip installed.
```

sudo apt install python3-pip

```
Install pynput - the script uses it to listen for key presses.
```

python3 -m pip install --user pynput==1.4

```
Copy the switch-layout.py somewhere in your home folder.
Edit the SWITCH_SHORTCUTS and LAYOUTS_COUNT at the top of the script accordingly to your needs.
Disable built-in layout-switch shortcut in your system, so it wouldn't interfere with the script. Also disable CapsLock default behavior in case you use it as switch key.
Run the script: python3 switch-layout.py. Try pressing the shortcut and see if it works. If it doesn't, feel free to open an issue. Maybe I'll be able to help. Press Ctrl+C to stop the script.
If it works, you can add this script to autostart programs in your DE to make it start automatically.
```